# How do I return array of strings from strings enclosed in square brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a string that follows `"[option1] [option2] [option3] some more text"`, how would I extract a array of strings from that string that goes like this `["option1", "option2", "option3"]` its a bit late at night so I'm sorry if I phrased this question badly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression to the string `match` method to do this. This uses both lookahead `(?=\])` and lookbehind `(?<=\[)` operators to check for brackets but *not* include those brackets in the result. Then, you want to lazily capture everything in between the brackets `.+?`. The `g` makes sure we do this globally (look for all matches, not just the first).

```js
const str = "[option1] [option2] [option3] some more text";
const matches = str.match(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a split function you can use to split a string into an array just do this

```
var nameOfString = "[option option option]"
let newString = nameOfString.replace(/[/g, "").replace(/]/g, "").split(" ");
```

then you can do newString[0] first word etc...